# How to extract single property from Python object when it is in a list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a Python object called `Profile` which has `first name` and `last name`.  I have an array called `Profiles` which is a collection of `Profile` objects:

```
Profiles = []
Profile  = {}
Profile['firstname'] = "foo"
Profile['lastname'] = "bar"
Profiles.append(Profile)
```

I need to post this array as json to a web service, however I only want to post the firstname property.

I'm posting the array like this:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(Profiles))
```

How can I modify my code to only post the first names?  I realise I can loop through and create a new list, but was wondering if there was an easier way?

Comment: You are looking for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the list and extract the desired elements from the `dict` using list comprehension.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps([p["firstname"] for p in Profiles]))
```

Comment: Perfect! One small question, what's the syntax for specifying 2 elements instead of 1?

Comment: `[[p["firstname"], p["lastname"]] for p in Profiles]`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
json.dumps([p['firstname'] for p in Profiles])
```

And for two fields, you can just write:

```
json.dumps([{'firstname':p['firstname'],'lastname':p['lastname']} for p in Profiles])
```